# Typescript function returning to a previous component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have case like

```
UserPage.tsx

...
return (
   <UserForm
     back={backMethod}
   />
)
...
```

and

```
UserForm.tsx


interface UserFormProps {
   back: () => ?? - what should I give here if we don't change URL?
}
```

Is it possible to point in TS to another component? In UserForm, I want to point to UserPage. We don't change the URL, we hide elements in UserPage.tsx

Comment: No, you just need to set the return type of the function, if function just redirects back and returns nothing, just set ```() => void```

Comment: I found something like `() => React.ReactNode;`

Comment: you would use it if your function returned a react node, but as I understood you just redirect back, so there is no need to do as you wrote

Comment: This is fine, we can close it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not hide other components directly in a function on the UserPage component